# Poincaré-Dulac for vector field

Tags: complex-analysis, dynamical-systems, complex-dynamics

[image]
In the above calculation of $w(z)$, why would a term containing $\frac{\partial}{\partial z_j}$ appear? Since all of the substitutions in the formula don't have anything containing derivative's.

Comment: Dasheng, could you please tell me where is this screenshot from?

Comment: @theDumbGeometer It's in the note of a course I took. I can send you a copy via email if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is not a derivative. It indicates the $j$th component.

Namely, if a vector field $f=f(z)$ has components $f_j(z)$, then we write
$$
f(z)=\sum_{j=1}^nf_j(z)\frac{\partial}{\partial z_j}.
$$